# Kiwi reporting to Bugzilla issue

Tags: kiwi-tcms

I want Kiwi to report bugs to Bugzilla. I have configured the Bugzilla bugtracker in the config. All fine so far.
I go to my test run an click on report. I select my bugzilla issue tracker and click on report.
Then I get: "Enable reporting to this Issue Tracker by configuring its base_url!"

But the Base URL is correct and also the credentials. On Kiwi side I also found the access token from bugzilla on disk.

So it seems the connection itself works and Kiwi goes wrong at a later point.

How can I make this working?

Kiwi is 6.2 runnig in a docker conrainer.
Bugzilla is 5.0.4 also in a container.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of what you've tried so far so we can reproduce your issue.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a genuine bug which should be fixed by
https://github.com/kiwitcms/Kiwi/commit/f4d2b835a9a6dd25b56d080f40caf0ab6f0972fc

can you rebuild your docker image from source and verify if this fixes the problem for you ?